# Auth in Universal React app with Passport

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I have an universal react app with React-router, Redux, Express and Sequelize for MySQL DB. I am trying to learn how to use Passport for JWT auth, and I have a question.

Is there any difference when setting passport in a frontend rendered app and an universal one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No difference.**

To authentication users in universal react apps we don't have to use JWT auth in server side.

We just need to read user authentication datas from cookie of client side and render pages with according to authenticated user from API server side.